# How can I check that iPhone's Bluetooth is connected to other device / accessories or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth

I am working on an application which includes Bluetooth connection pairing. So I want to know if bluetooth is connected to other device or any accessories?

Check that bluetooth is paired or not in iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `CBCentralManager` to retrieve connected bluetooth device to your device. When your bluetooth device is on (`CBCentralManager` status == `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn`), call this function:

```
func retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices serviceUUIDs: [CBUUID]) -> [CBPeripheral]
```

It gives your the list of UUID of all service connected to your iPhone.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518924-retrieveconnectedperipherals

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Thanks